# How to do server side rendering using Angular universal in Angular 2 with Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

Does GoogleBot render Angular 2 without Angular Universal?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please improve your question. Please also check the help menu about how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of theory regarding making the meaning out from javascript generated content to SEO bots. But it is better to be safer side to feed bots. If your site is heavily dependent on SEO.

Otherwise universal is good option.

Answer (score 0):

Angular Universal was creating for CEO purpose so that bots could render your dynamic HTML-content properly.

Angular 2 is only a front-end framework without server rendering - you can check it just seeing HTML-code of your dynamic page, there are only Angular's {{...}}. So the content of your HTML-page will not be rendered by bots.

If you would like to use Angular Universal I would recommend to begin with some Starter Project. I use for my Angular Universal project the following one: https://github.com/angular/universal-starter